# Kruskal Wallis Test and subsetting

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis

Are you please able to assist in performing a Krustal Wallis test using a subset of my data? I would like to be able to test for differences in "N" between "Producers".

```
names(Isotope.Data)
[1] "Species"         "Name"            "Group"           "Simple_Group"       "Trophic_Group"  
[6] "Sample"          "N"               "C"
```

In my csv.file I have a column "Trophic Group" which separates Consumers and Producers.

```
table(Isotope.Data$Trophic_Group)

Consumer Producers  
    61         18
```

Under the column heading Simple_Group, I have three Producers - Rhodophyta, Seagrass and Phaeophyceae

```
table(Isotope.Data$Simple_Group)

 Abalone  Loliginidae      Octopus Phaeophyceae   Rhodophyta     Seagrass      Teleost 
      24            2           12            6            9            3           20 
Tunicate 
       3
```

I have tried numerous things, but I get various error messages. 
Would anyone be able to improve on the following code?

```
kruskal.test(C ~ Simple_Group, data = Isotope.Data, subset = Isotope.Data$Trophic_Group = "Producers")
```

P.S. I have created a separate CSV.file which only includes Primary Producers. However a subsequent Dunn-test of multiple comparisons, used to determine which levels differed from each other provides different significance levels to those which includes both Consumers and Producers.

Comment: I have several questions: What is C when you call `kruskal.test`? Which is the error message you get when running the code?

Comment: C refers to Carbon, and N refers to Nitrogen. I will run separate tests to test for differences in C and N between consumers and producers

Comment: The error is:     
Error: unexpected '=' in "kruskal.test(C ~ Simple_Group, data = Isotope.Data, subset = Isotope.Data$Trophic_Group ="

Comment: You need to use `==` and not `=`.

Comment: Thanks Roman, I have tried that also. I get the following error.... Error in kruskal.test.default(numeric(0), integer(0)) : 
  all observations are in the same group

Comment: To make comparisons you need individuals from two different groups, and it seems like you have all of them from only one group.

Comment: I have three different groups: Phaeophyceae, Rhodophyta and Seagrass. I would like to see whether there is a significant difference in C or N between these three producers.

Answer (score 2):

Will maybe this answer be helpful? Based on @user295691 answer:

[Kruskal-Wallis test: create lapply function to subset data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180546/kruskal-wallis-test-create-lapply-function-to-subset-data-frame)

Here you identify individual groups what you want to test differences between, and use split, to correctly define subsetting of your data frame.

Dummy example:

```
# create data
val<-runif(60, min = 0, max = 100)
distance<-floor(runif(60, min=1, max=3))
phase<-rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 20)

df<-data.frame(val, distance, phase)

# get unique groups
ii<-unique(df$phase)

# run Kruskal test, specify the subset
kruskal.test(df$val ~df$distance,
             subset = phase == "c")
```

And now apply the `kruskal.test` to each group using `split`:

```
lapply(split(df, df$phase), function(d) { kruskal.test(val ~ distance, data=d) })
```

or create a function:

```
lapply(ii, function(i) { kruskal.test(df$val ~ df$distance, subset=df$phase==i )})
```

**Both produces test results for each group**:

```
[[1]]

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  df$val by df$distance
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 0.14881, df = 1, p-value = 0.6997


[[2]]

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  df$val by df$distance
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 0.11688, df = 1, p-value = 0.7324


[[3]]

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  df$val by df$distance
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 0.0059524, df = 1, p-value = 0.9385
```

Or just **get the p-values** (notice the addition of `$p.value` after the `kruskal.test`):

```
lapply(ii, function(i) { 
  kruskal.test(df$val ~ df$distance, 
               subset=df$phase==i )$p.value
}
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `map()` function from the package `purrr` to apply function in each group once splited

```
library(purrr)
test <- df %>% group_split(phase) %>% map(~kruskal.test(.,val ~ distance))
test
```